# Area Chart Not Aligned

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am having a problem where my area chart doesn't seem to align with the values in the middle of the chart, only at the end. How can I make it a straight line as the one close to 1 Jun? I already checked the dataset and it appears correct, it starts and ends on the same dates. Any ideas?

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to check the settings for empty cells.

Please right click the chart > Select Data > Hidden and Empty Cells > Show empty cells as **Gaps** > OK > OK.

[image]